# Sitecore 9.3 EXM - SQL timeout issue

Tags: exm, sql-database, marketing-automation

While doing Marketing automation in the send email step I am seeing below error in the logs. It is continuously attempting to send email and logging this error. It is able to send the email sometimes.
Changed the connection timeout in SQL to unlimited but still the error is same.

```
ManagedPoolThread #5 22:08:07 INFO  1 SMTP connections disposed.
18812 22:16:42 INFO  Registered email: test@exm.com
18812 22:17:12 ERROR Exception: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
Message: Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
The statement has been terminated.
Source: .Net SqlClient Data Provider
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.RunParser(BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.CopyBatchesAsyncContinuedOnSuccess(BulkCopySimpleResultSet internalResults, String updateBulkCommandText, CancellationToken cts, TaskCompletionSource`1 source)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.CopyBatchesAsyncContinued(BulkCopySimpleResultSet internalResults, String updateBulkCommandText, CancellationToken cts, TaskCompletionSource`1 source)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.CopyBatchesAsync(BulkCopySimpleResultSet internalResults, String updateBulkCommandText, CancellationToken cts, TaskCompletionSource`1 source)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServerInternalRestContinuedAsync(BulkCopySimpleResultSet internalResults, CancellationToken cts, TaskCompletionSource`1 source)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServerInternalRestAsync(CancellationToken cts, TaskCompletionSource`1 source)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServerInternalAsync(CancellationToken ctoken)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.WriteRowSourceToServerAsync(Int32 columnCount, CancellationToken ctoken)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(IDataReader reader)
   at Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.Core.Data.SqlDbEcmDataProvider.AddToDispatchQueue(Guid messageId, MessageType messageType, IEnumerable`1 recipients, Dictionary`2 customPersonTokens, Dictionary`2 customQueryStringParameters)
   at Sitecore.EmailCampaign.Cm.Dispatch.DispatchManager.AddRecipientToDispatchQueue(DispatchNewsletterArgs args, ContactIdentifier contactIdentifier)
   at Sitecore.EmailCampaign.Cm.SendingManager.SendStandardCore(ContactIdentifier contactIdentifier)
   at Sitecore.EmailCampaign.Cm.UI.Handlers.AutomatedMessageHandler.SendMessage(AutomatedMessage message)

Nested Exception

Exception: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception
Message: The wait operation timed out
```

**Logs for the successful Mail Sent**

```
ManagedPoolThread #12 21:58:05 INFO  0 SMTP connections disposed.
9044 21:58:06 INFO  Time to send: 2284 ms
9044 21:58:06 INFO  Dispatch Message (Subscription Confirmation): Finished
  Result:          FINISHED
  Message Id:      {95B09361-3A2F-4109-A87D-A3574DA01D63}
  Message Path:    /sitecore/content/Email/Messages/Service Messages/Self-Service Subscription/Subscription Confirmation
  Recipients Processed:    50
  Message Total Sent Recipients:    50
  Message Total Failed Recipients:  0
  Message Total Skipped Recipients (Enable log DEBUG level to see why):  0
  Included Recipient Lists: 
  Excluded Recipient Lists:
```

Comment: Is it the same email over and over or several?

Comment: It is the same email

Comment: If you look in the EXMMaster Database, look at the table "DispatchQueue" and tell me how many items are in it. If it's in the millions, it's not getting cleared out appropriately, most likely the Bulkcopy SQL command is timing out.  Also look at the PK_DispatchQueue Cluster Index and report on the fragmentation of that index.